Huggingface Trainer Stops Before Completing All Epochs
I am using the Huggingface Trainer for a sequence classification task with the following configuration:

num_train_epochs=5
save_strategy="epoch"
evaluation_strategy="epoch"
load_best_model_at_end=False

However, training stops after the 4th epoch, even though I expect it to complete all 5 epochs.
Here is a snippet of my training arguments and Trainer setup:
enter image description here
outputTable
I suspect it might be related to early stopping behavior, gradient accumulation, or some other parameter interaction.
I've also ensured no early stopping callback is being used.
How to resolve this issue?
What I Tried:
I set num_train_epochs=5 in the TrainingArguments and used the Trainer from the Huggingface Transformers library. My goal was to train the model for exactly 5 epochs. I verified that no early stopping callback or additional termination logic was applied.
What I Expected:
The training process should run for all 5 epochs, logging metrics and saving checkpoints after each epoch as configured.
What Happened:
The training stopped after the 4th epoch without any error messages. The logs indicated the end of the training process prematurely, even though num_train_epochs was explicitly set to 5.

Welcome to SO. Please do not post screenshots of code or error messages, see how to create a [mre].
